# How do I plot a dictionary (KeyValuePair) in a graph (zedgraph) in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, plot, visual-studio-2017, zedgraph

I have a Dictionary with Key and Value Pairs. I need to create a Line Graph on zedGraph, plotting the Key in the X-Axis and the Value in the Y-Axis. I am using Visual Studio 2017.

the Key is a DateTime type. The Value is a string type.

I was thinking of creating 2 arrays, an X-Axis Array and a Y-Axis array.

Any other/quicker/more optimal suggestions?

I have already tried converting the DateTime values into Ticks, but i cannot create a loop to print them. It gives me an Error:

```
void addGraph(List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, string>> dataDic)
        {
            DateTime DT = new DateTime();


            long TimeTicks = DT.Ticks;


            foreach (var element in TimeTicks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
```

Expectation:
Output of all values in the TimeTicks variable/array.

Reality/Error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'long' because 'long' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'    TCD_Interface   C:\Users\Z0044MTW\Desktop\TCD_Interface\TCD_Interface\Plant_OV.cs   156 Active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot enumerate – use as source in a `foreach` loop – something that is not a collection (or looks very like a collection).

A `long` is a singular value, not a collection, so cannot be enumerated.

You need to iterate over the set of points you want to plot, not the values of the coordinates of those points.

(Whether separate arrays extracted from the underlying dictionary makes sense depends on the details of the graph library.)

Comment: can you maybe go into a little more detail? what do you mean by this: "You need to iterate over the set of points you want to plot, not the values of the coordinates of those points." What set of points? Are the Key Pair Values coordinates, rather than points?

Comment: @ShahbazShahSyed "I have a Dictionary": that collection of points.

Comment: but i do need to convert the Key Value Pairs into an int or double right?

Comment: @ShahbazShahSyed Depends on the details of zedgraph for `DateTime`, but likely for the values being strings you will need to convert. The function used to convert depends on the data held in the string, it could be as easy as `Int32.Parse`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I converted the strings into a double type (i tried everything, this and decimal type worked, im going with double type). I used the "Ticks method" on the DateTime type, which resulted in an array of "long types". Is it possible to plot the values with these types into a graph?

Comment: @ShahbazShahSyed See above for the `DateTime` values: it depends on the details of the graphing library. Some will allow a date/time axis, others you'll need to do something else (but that depends on what you want to show).

Comment: on the X-Axis i want to show the DateTime, on the Y-Axis the correlated Value. X-Axis would be an array of long types, Y-Axis would be an Array of double type. Will it be possible to plot this on zedGraph?